# Why aren't my young Bonsai Plant seedlings growing well?

Tags: diagnosis, plant-health, tree-care, containers, bonsai

My bonsai plant is not growing well. I used a [Mini Bonsai Kit](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0762409746). With 6 seeds, I was able to sprout only 2 plants and one is almost wilting. The other one was growing well for a week but it also seems to be dying soon. Have people used this kit? I have followed the exact instructions given in the book that came along with it. What could have gone wrong? What are the special bonsai pots? How big should they be?

Answer (score 3):

The comments from the product page indicate that you get jack pine seeds.

If you didn't keep them cold and damp in the fridge for 4 to 8 weeks you would see poor germination. Special pots are not as important at the moment as other requirements.

The Jack Pine ([Pinus Banksiana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jack_pine)) is an evergreen from the Northern Hemisphere.  It needs to be grown outside for the light levels and seasonal cues that a diminishing day length provide.

Even your little plant needs to have a winter where it is protected from drying winds but exposed to cold temperatures.

Another [forum](http://ibonsaiclub.forumotion.com/t14527-pinus-banksiana-jack-pine) notes this about the Jack Pine as Bonsai:

- they don't like to have their roots disturbed.
- "Use a soil that will last and avoid repotting"
- Their normal environment has a neutral to acid pH so they are sensitive to long term pH changes from alkaline water
- Fertilize very lightly, if at all, or the needles look "ratty"